# How to change the order of rows in a dynamically created table?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

If I have a dynamically created table that looks something like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Hours</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Weds</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td>Fri</td>
    <td>7.5</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>Mon</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>       
</table>
```

How can I order the rows Monday - Friday? Preferably using jQuery.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted.

Comment: I have edited out the *thanks* note from the question because they are considered as fluff and are generally not required to be present. I have also removed the *any suggestions* from title because it is understood that you are asking for suggestions :) Finally, I have removed the tr tag because that tag is meant to be used for *nix utility and not HTML tables (please hover over the tag to find out usage details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a weekday hash to turn three-letter day abbreviations into numbers. The rows are removed from the table, ordered, and inserted back in:

```js
var weekHash = {'Sun':0,'Mon':1,'Tue':2,'Wed':3,'Thu':4,'Fri':5,'Sat':6};
var header = $('tr:first');
var days = $('tr').not(header);
var orderedDays = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    days.each(function(){
        if (i == weekHash[$(this).find('td:first').html()])
        {
            orderedDays.push(this);
        }
    });
}
$('tr').not(header).remove;
for (o in orderedDays)
{
    $('table').append(orderedDays[o]);    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Day</th><th>Hours</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wed</td><td>7</td>
      </tr>   
      <tr>
        <td>Fri</td><td>7.5</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>Mon</td><td>8</td>
      </tr>       
    </table>
```

You may need to change the weekday abbreviations, though, as I noticed your table says 'Weds' rather than my 'Wed'.

Comment: With a few adjustments that worked perfectly for my application. Thank you very much!